# Best way to get lat and long from gps and sending to a server to get data back using expandable list view android

Tags: android

what is the best way to design an expandable list view, the details for the list view will come from server after the device sends the latitude and longitude to the server.

I am early learner on AsyncTask, as User Interface might freeze when getting lat,long and sending the same to the server and getting back branch details. Some example, pointers would be helpful. 
Looking forward to reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link for usage of AsyncTask:
http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/asynctask-call-web-services-in-android/

Basically, once you get the `AsyncTask` going all you need to do is to populate the `ExpandableListAdapter` with your data and call `notifyDataChanged` on the adapter. That should populate the list with your items. There's plenty of tutorials available on how to write a custom `ExpandableListAdapter` should you need one. Just use Google to find the item.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentioned `AsynTask`, once you get the coordinates (in `OnLocationChanged()` execute the instance of `AsyncTask`, this means the listview will be repopulated every time there is update in your location) send the coordinates in `doInBackground()` method and when you are done with the getting/sending in the `onPostExecute()` method try to populate the expandable listview with the data from the server.